# How to convert the Date String with time zone to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

How to convert the Date String "2012-05-03 06:03:00 +0000" to NSDate. I user the code below, but it does not work:

```
NSDateFormatter *datFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate* date = [datFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  NSString *dateStr = @"2012-05-03 06:03:00 +0000";
  NSDateFormatter *datFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [datFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
  NSDate* date = [datFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
  NSLog(@"date: %@", [datFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

This code prints `date: 2012-05-03 09:03:00 +0300`

It works. Also don't forget to set the date formatter's timeZone that you're targeting

Comment: like that `datFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done this way:-

```
NSDateFormatter *datFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Yout TimeZone"]];
[datFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *string = @"2012-05-03 06:03:00 +0000";
NSDate* date = [datFormat dateFromString:string];
```