# convert string data " 03:12:00 May 06, 2014 MDT" into nsdate " 03-05-2014 " in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having Date like `"payment_date" = "03:12:00 May 06, 2014 MDT";`.
 
But i want to convert this data into `NSDate` like `"06-05-2014"`

Please help me, 
don't know to handle it..

i got the answer from [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

```
 __block NSDate *detectedDate;

//Detect.
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingAllTypes error:nil];
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:t_date
                           options:kNilOptions
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [t_date length])
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{ detectedDate = result.date;

    NSDate *d=result.date;

}


 ];
```

Comment: already available solution on stackoverflow.

Comment: can you please give me that link ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again

Comment: @user3620252:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570593/how-to-convert-the-date-string-with-time-zone-to-nsdate

Comment: Make sure you read and understand the documentation for NSDate. There are tons and tons of questions here where misunderstanding of NSDate makes people think they got wrong results when the result is actually correct.

Comment: @gnasher729: Or the result is wrong and they think it is correct :-)

Comment: Try Google "Objective-C convert date".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to date in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c)

Answer (score -2):

EDITS

```
NSString *str = @"03:12:00 October 06, 2014 MDT";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

str = [str substringFromIndex:9];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[str substringToIndex:[str length] -3]];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: This code ignores the given timezone "MDT". And using a fixed range (9, 13) substring is not the best idea. What if the month has more than three letters?

Comment: @MartinR : Actually i gave the solution according to the question's requirement.

Comment: Well, it converts the string "03:12:00 May 06, 2014 MDT", but it fails for "03:12:00 October 06, 2014 MDT" ...

Comment: @MartinR Sir you are absolutely right. my application crashes when i am having date from "april" or another months...

Comment: @MartinR & Darshan_Ethan : You can check my code now.  Happy codding. :)